# Can't merge values by function mutate for logistic regression

Tags: r, variables, merge, case

```
mutate(Vira_respondenta = case_when(Vira_respondenta=="Ostatní Křesťanské" ~ "Věřící")
                                Vira_respondenta=="Římskokatolické" ~ "Věřící")
                                Vira_respondenta=="Českobratrské evangelické" ~ "Věřící")
                                Vira_respondenta=="Československé husitské" ~ "Věřící")
                                Vira_respondenta=="Ostatní mimokřesťanské" ~ "Věřící")
                                Vira_respondenta=fct_relevel(Vira_respondenta,"Věřící")) %>%
```

mutate(Vira_respondenta = case_when(Vira_respondenta=="Žádné",
Vira_respondenta=fct_relevel(Vira_respondenta, "Nevěřící")) %>%

Hello, everyone.
The thing is that I my dependent variable is text based (8 values).
The problem is that I need to use logistic regression.
The variable is related to religion and different churches, so I decided to make it binary by renaming it "Believers(Věřící)" "Non-believers" (Žádné) . Thank you for any advice (im using only one df)

Answer (score 0):

If it is the case that only "Žádné" corresponds to "Non-believers" and everything else means "Believers", I would do this:

```r
data_lm$Vira_respondenta <- ifelse(data_lm$Vira_respondenta=='Žádné', 'Non-believer', 'Believer')
```

Comment: Sorry for my fault, now im working with "data_lm"

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I would need to merge the above values into a single "Believer" value and the Non-believer value into the "Non-believer" ("Žádné") value label. I don't really understand the code, but thanks for trying!

Comment: I don't think I understand. Can you show us part of your data and what the desired outcome should look like?

Comment: Of course, thank you very much for your kindness. The error of your misunderstanding will be on my side. I am a beginner in R studies, but the demands of our school project are high (from my point of view).
Here is: PrtSc https://ibb.co/0XJ6KjP
I need to merge all the values from the Vira_respondent column. 
These are respondents who either subscribed to a church or none.
So my result should be binary data for a logistic regression.

Comment: According to my tutor, I have to merge all churches into the value "Believers" and respondents who stated "None" - Non-Believers. Into the value of Non-Believers

Comment: That should be what my code does. I changed it now to create a new column, see the edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but unfortunately I still need to merge all church members/believers into just one value and that is "Believers". I hope I'm explaining this well, thank you again for your willingness.

Comment: Does my code do what you need now? If not, what should be different?

Comment: Yes, your code separated believers from non-believers, but unfortunately it did not combine the category of churches into a single value. 
This makes the set too large, so I should merge all church members into one value.
https://ibb.co/Qp632yG

Comment: What do you mean by "combine the category of churches into a single value"? I thought you wanted to change your eight-value variable into a binary one.

Comment: Offff, I don't know exactly how to describe it. What I need is to merge all the believers into one category, as you yourself have done, except that I need to merge the churches themselves - because of the size of the data_lm. Am I writing this clearly? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I'm not sure.. After it is done, do you expect data_lm to have less rows than the 1200 it has now?

Comment: Yes, that's right! By combining all the churches into one category, I'm also taking away a significant amount of values.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? How many rows do you expect data_lm to have then?

Comment: Yes, I am. I don't know exactly how many data_lm will contain because I don't know how many believing respondents are in that category.
But I would need to merge all the categories from the figure into one, namely "Believers". "Žadné" means that people are not religious

Comment: Here are the categories I would like to merge as believers - věřící in my language
https://ibb.co/fS6SmYf

Comment: Restricting ourselves just to the 14 lines of data_lm visible in the image you shared, what would it look like after the "merging"?

Comment: Just like in your code. 
The only difference would be that these 14 lines would be treated as one value.

Comment: Now I'm pretty sure I don't understand. Treated by what? If you want to run a logistic regression you just need to recode your dependent variable so that it is binary. No need to reduce the dataset in any way, 1200 rows of data should be fine.

Comment: I know I do, but unfortunately my professor insists that I have to reduce the lines I've marked.